# Adding name_col and name_alpha to swimplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using the swimplot package to make a swimmers plot that is ordered by drug (X or O), colored by base (A, B, or C), and then either colored by bar or shading for tx_line (1,2,3,4,5 or 6). Ideally, I would also "gap" from 150-450 days so that pt 5  doesn't make the rest look so short. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong with the name_col and name_alpha, and how swimmer points can be separated out (note: it combined categories and ran out of symbols)?

```
dummy<-data.frame(ptid=c(1,2,3,4,5),PFS=c(50,30,120,3,500),base=c("A","B","C","A","B"),drug=c("X","O","X","O","X"),response_time=c(20,10,100,NA,100),BoR=c("PR","PD","CR","PD","CR"),tx_line=c("3","5","1","4","1"),on_tx=c(1,NA,1,NA,NA))
dummy$PFS_fudge<-dummy$PFS+10

clinical_plot<-swimmer_plot(df=dummy,id="ptid",end="PFS",name_fill="base",id_order="drug",name_col="tx_line",name_alpha="drug",alpha=0.75,width=0.8,col="black")
a<-clinical_plot + 
#BoR points
swimmer_points(df_points=dummy,id="ptid",time="response_time",name_shape="BoR",size=2.5,fill='white',col='black') + 
  #tx line points
swimmer_points(df_points=dummy,id="ptid",time=-15,name_shape="tx_line",size=2.5,fill='white',col='black')+
#continuation arrows
  swimmer_arrows(df_arrows=dummy,id="ptid",arrow_start="PFS_fudge",
cont = "on_tx",type =
 "closed",cex=1,show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: current output here]

Comment: Are you asking for a discontinuous axis?

Comment: 1)Why name_col and name_alpha aren't working, 2) how to handle multiple swim_points (and exceeding 5 symbols, and 3) discontinuous axis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use directly `ggplot2` (`swimplot` is just a wrapper that's limiting your options)... but, with the code you written it should be something like that:

```
clinical_plot<-swimmer_plot(df=dummy,id="ptid",end="PFS",name_fill="base",id_order="drug",
                            name_col="tx_line",name_alpha="drug",alpha=0.75,width=0.8,col="black")
clinical_plot + 
  #BoR points
  swimmer_points(df_points=dummy,id="ptid",time="response_time",name_shape="BoR",
                 size=2.5,fill='white',col='black') + 
  #tx line points
  swimmer_points(df_points=dummy,id="ptid",time=-15,name_shape="tx_line",
                 size=2.5,fill='white',col='black')+
  #continuation arrows
  swimmer_arrows(df_arrows=dummy,id="ptid",arrow_start="PFS_fudge",
                 cont = "on_tx",type =
                   "closed",cex=1,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  # ---> you should to identify each of your values with a specific shape for avoiding confusions
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("1" = 0, "3" = 1, "4" = 2, "5" = 3, "CR" = 4, "PD" = 5, "PR" = 6), 
                     breaks = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "CR", "PD", "PR"))
```

[image]

In `ggplot2` is (apparently) more complicated but it will offer you more options in the future:

```
ggplot(dummy, aes(y = reorder(ptid, drug), x = PFS)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = base), width = 0.8) + 
  #BoR points
  geom_point(aes(y = reorder(ptid, drug), x = response_time, shape = BoR), size = 3) + 
  #tx line points
  geom_point(aes(y = reorder(ptid, drug), x = -20, shape = tx_line), size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("1" = 0, "3" = 1, "4" = 2, "5" = 3, "CR" = 4, "PD" = 5, "PR" = 6), 
                     breaks = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "CR", "PD", "PR")) + 
  #continuation arrows
  geom_segment(data = dummy[!is.na(dummy$on_tx),], 
               aes(x = PFS_fudge, xend = PFS_fudge+1, yend = reorder(ptid, drug)),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")), size = 1)
  theme_bw()
```

[image]